# How can I interpret the numbers for count correctly

Tags: natural-numbers

I know that the numbers we use to identify a group by its quantity, the natural numbers we use for it, we have tens, hundreds, units, milli million ... etc

1 is like O
2 is like OO
3 is like OOO
4 is like OOOO
5 is like OOOOO
6 is like OOOOOO
7 is like OOOOOOO
8 is like OOOOOOOO
9 is like OOOOOOOOO

Then we have the 10 in which I add one more circle to represent that amount and that is called ten, then the tens reach 90 and if I add 10 more items I get a hundred

It is correct to say that if I have
15, I have 10 with 5, a dozen with 5 units and the ten grows to 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 for every 10 units that I add when I'm counting?

Is it correct to say that if I have 10 I have a ten with 0 units?

and if I have 105 I have a hundred with 5 units and 0 tens?

Why are numbers combined in this way to generate new quantities? I do not understand that very well

Can I see it so that the whole quantities start from 1 to 9 and after 9 a number is added to the number (the number 1 accompanied by a 0 or the number 1 with the other numbers in 0)?

Is it correct to say that a number is added after 9 and leave the other numbers in 0 to count again and increase the number with 10, units, hundreds, thousands and so on?

I do not know if this justifies my question (because I know it can be stupid), but I am having problems with my mental health and lately it is difficult for me to reason and perform tasks that I used to do without problems, I do not speak native English and I am helping myself with a translator

I do not know if I write my question well, I'm new to the community, I know how to publish questions related to programming but I do not know how this section of the page works, so

Answer (score 1):

Both of these are correct.

> Is it correct to say that if I have 10 I have a ten with 0 units?
>
> and if I have 105 I have a hundred with 5 units and 0 tens?

I think you are trying to explain positional notation using English words.

Your English is awkward (as you know) but you do grasp the idea.